# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql, sum

Tenho um select dentro da minha query utilizado para soma e toda vez que adiciono o campo GRADE da tabela PA_XCPNT_EVTHST.GRADE, recebo o erro ORA-00907. Se eu retiro o grade do select, funciona perfeitamente. Esse é o select original:

```
( SELECT SUM( SCORE ) FROM QUIZ_DETAILS Q1 WHERE Q1.STUD_ID = QUIZ_DETAILS.STUD_ID
AND Q1.RN = '1' GROUP BY Q1.STUD_ID ) AS SOMA_SCORE
```

Esse foi o select após minha alteração (que não sei se está correta):

```
( SELECT SUM( SCORE + GRADE ) FROM QUIZ_DETAILS Q1 DADOS D1 WHERE Q1.STUD_ID = QUIZ_DETAILS.STUD_ID D1.STUD_ID = DADOS.STUD_ID
AND Q1.RN = '1' GROUP BY Q1.STUD_ID ) AS SOMA_SCORE
```

Conseguem me ajudar??

Answer (score 1):

Além de colocar o AND na segunda condição do where adicionar vírgula entre os objetos tabelas:

```
(SELECT SUM( SCORE + GRADE )
   FROM QUIZ_DETAILS, Q1 DADOS D1 
  WHERE Q1.STUD_ID = QUIZ_DETAILS.STUD_ID 
    AND D1.STUD_ID = DADOS.STUD_ID
    AND Q1.RN = '1' GROUP BY Q1.STUD_ID ) AS SOMA_SCORE
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que sua segunda consulta está correta, acredito que o erro seja você não ter colocado o `AND` entre a primeira e a segunda condição do `where`. Tenta assim:

```
(SELECT SUM( SCORE + GRADE )
   FROM QUIZ_DETAILS Q1 DADOS D1 
  WHERE Q1.STUD_ID = QUIZ_DETAILS.STUD_ID 
    AND D1.STUD_ID = DADOS.STUD_ID
    AND Q1.RN = '1' GROUP BY Q1.STUD_ID ) AS SOMA_SCORE
```

Comment: rLinhares o erro continua ocorrendo mesmo utilizando o AND.